# Cargar .PDF en binario desde una web a Cordova

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

Estoy haciendo una llamada para mostrar un `PDF` en mi app de `Cordova`
La petición en `ajax` me devuelve este tipo de información :

```
%PDF-1.7
%����
1 0 obj
<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(es-ES) /StructTreeRoot 14 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</Font<</F1 5 0 R/F2 7 0 R/F3 9 0 R>>/XObject<</Image11 11 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 917>>
stream
x��V[O�X~���p�V>��eUU[B
�J�B���J�-�S�H����  -��Y�������'۴�E1k����۶-f7��]��z�%�~ߔ�E�\UE���7o��ɘO����dR�0l�$�'�v,
V��z8 �PL�����e�r����pp�E6.�6�0L�`
```

El problema que tengo es que no sé como convertir todo lo anterior en un `pdf`
Estoy intentado esto pero no me funciona.

```
new Promise(function () {
        var options = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: URL_OBTENER_DOCUMENTO_PASARELA,
            data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
            contentType: "application/json;",
            dataType: 'text',
            headers: {
                "Authorization": localStorage.getItem(TOKEN)
            },
            success: function (respuesta) {

                var file = new Blob([respuesta], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                window.open(fileURL);

                cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                    respuesta,
                    'application/pdf',
                    {
                        error: function (e) {
                            alert("Error abriendo el archivo");
                        },
                        success: function () {
                            //console.log('file opened successfully');
                        }
                    }
                );

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('errrrrrrrrroooo');

            }
        }
        $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {

        });
    });
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: usas la variable `fileWriter` pero no esta definida en ningun lado. De donde lo obtienes? si hay mas codigo relacionado agregalo para entender esta parte.

Comment: Perdona, se me había colado es linea de las pruebas. ya la he modificado

Answer (score 0):

`cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open()` espera como primer parámetro una ruta de archivo local, por lo que debes transformar el contenido o descargarlo en una ruta local antes de abrirlo con fileOpener2:

```
var blob = new Blob([respuesta], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var pathFile = cordova.file.documentsDirectory
// escribir blob en archivo
cordova.file.writeFile(pathFile, fileName, blob, true)
        .then(function(success) {
            // archivo guardado, mostrar usando ruta + nombre
            var savedFileName = pathFile + fileName
            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                savedFileName,
                'application/pdf',
                {
                    error: function (e) {
                        alert("Error abriendo el archivo "+ fileName);
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        //console.log('file opened successfully');
                    }
                }
            );

        }, function(error) {

            alert("error writing file")

        });
```

Nota:
cordova.file.writeFile es parte del plugin `cordova-plugin-file`
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

Comment: hola gracias,  no funciona : / .   savedFile te refieres a savedFileName  no ?
por otro lado en cordova.file.writeFile me dice que no existe esa funcion : (

Comment: SI, deberia decir `savedFileName` y `fileName` en el codigo lo deje como referencia por lo que debes revisar y probarlo localmente. Lo he corregido y agregue una nota de que necesitas el plugin `cordova-plugin-file` para realizar la escritura en la carpeta local.

Comment: Ok gracias por las modificaciones. Puede ser que algún carácter de la cadena que me llega este mal?, me refiero a todo este tipo de cosas x��V[O�X~���p�V>��eUU[B
�J�B���J�-�S�H����  -��Y�������'۴�E1k����۶-f7��]��z�%�~ߔ�E�\UE���7o��ɘO����dR�0l�$�'�v,
V��z8 �PL�����e�r����pp�E6.�6